# Generate XML in QT like JAXB

Tags: c++, xml, qt, jaxb, codesynthesis

I generated a C++ class with CodeSynthesis from an XSD file. Now I want to create a C++ object, fill it with data and serialize it into XML or JSON format. **How can i generate the XML?** I also use the framework Qt. It should look like JAXB. For example (JavaCode):

```
Worker w = new Worker();
w.setName("Peter");
w.setStreet("...");
String xml = "XMLGenerator".generate(w);`
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

There is a hello world example in the documentation for **[CodeSynthesis XSD](http://codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/)** where a C++ object is created and then being serialized into XML.

Read more about it in:

[C++/Tree Mapping Getting Started Guide](http://codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/documentation/cxx/tree/guide/) (Section *2.5 Adding Serialization*)

Answer (score 0):

You can create XML files in Qt using DOM classes. DOM works by representing the entire XML document as a tree of node objects in memory.
:

```
QDomDocument document;

QDomElement d = document.createElement( "document" );
d.setAttribute( "name", "DocName" );

QDomElement a = document.createElement( "author" );
a.setAttribute( "name", "AuthorName" );

QDomText text = document.createTextNode( "Some text" );

document.appendChild( d );
d.appendChild( a );
d.appendChild( text );

//Writing to a file

QFile file( "simple.xml" );
if( !file.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text ) )
{
qDebug( "Failed to open file for writing." );
return -1;
}
QTextStream stream( &file );
stream << document.toString();
file.close();
```

Comment: This is the way i was looking for: 
http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsd/documentation/cxx/tree/guide/#2